# Transform some substrings from many rows to a new table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to transform this output from the row "topic"...

```
SMARTBASE/N0184/1/MOISTURE/value
SMARTBASE/N0184/1/MOISTURE/unit
SMARTBASE/N0184/1/MOISTURE/timestamp
SMARTBASE/N0184/1/CONDUCTIVITY/value
SMARTBASE/N0184/1/CONDUCTIVITY/unit
SMARTBASE/N0184/1/CONDUCTIVITY/timestamp
```

to a new table like:

`SENSORS|MOISTURE(value)|MOISTURE(unit)|CONDUCTIVITY(value)|CONDUCTIVITY(unit)
N0184|0.41437244624|Raw VWC|0.5297062938712509|mS/cm`

first line: values of topic(row), second line: values of value(row)(values of mqtt-topics)

but that's a sensor of 500++... SMARTBASE is not always SMARTBASE, so regexp _... is not a good idea ... At the end this should be saved as a view.

Is that even possible? I don't know how to implement it... or how to start with it. to transform a row in a table, I can use the pivot-function, but the rest, I don't know.

my main problem: How can I access the individual values of the topic?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54305736/edit) with a [MCVE] including: the DDL statements for your source and destination tables; DML statements for the sample data in your source data; the expected output for your source data.

Comment: *"SMARTBASE is not always SMARTBASE"*. But there is always something there, right? So you could use a very broad regex to capture the first occurrence on `/`. Beyond that, what is the significance of the `/1/`? Why don't you want the timestamps? Does the sensor output **guarantee** that you will always have those six rows together in that order? Can output from different sensors be interleaved? How do you identify which MOISTURE readings go with which CONDUCTIVITY readings?

Comment: First right, sry my example was "false", my mqtt-structure is allways like

3051/006/1902HT1318/A1/MOISTURE/N0170/1/VALUE or 
PKH//CONTAINER 9//MOISTURE/N0311/1/VALUE.  /1/ is the port of the sensor. here is the defintion of topic-structure
<BUILDING>/<ROOM>/<COMPARTIMENT>/<SUB-COMPARTIMENT>/<SENSOR_TYPE>/<SENSOR>/<PORT><[VALUE|TIMESTAMP|UNIT]>

i want the timestamp, but for my problem is this not important. i want to use the timestamp and sensor(id) in order to connect MOISTURE and CONDUCTIVITY of specific sensor.

Comment: But it may be missing, for example, the room or the sub_compartiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the substring components of your `topic` column and then use `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( topic, value ) AS 
SELECT 'SMARTBASE/N0184/1/MOISTURE/value',         '0.414' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SMARTBASE/N0184/1/MOISTURE/unit',          'Raw VWC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SMARTBASE/N0184/1/MOISTURE/timestamp',     '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SMARTBASE/N0184/1/CONDUCTIVITY/value',     '0.529' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SMARTBASE/N0184/1/CONDUCTIVITY/unit',      'mS/cm' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SMARTBASE/N0184/1/CONDUCTIVITY/timestamp', '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT SENSOR_TYPE,
       SENSOR,
       TO_NUMBER( moisture_value ) AS moisture_value,
       moisture_unit,
       TO_TIMESTAMP( moisture_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS moisture_timestamp,
       TO_NUMBER( conductivity_value ) AS conductivity_value,
       conductivity_unit,
       TO_TIMESTAMP( conductivity_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS conductivity_timestamp
FROM   (
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( topic, '[^/]+', 1, 1 ) AS sensor_type,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( topic, '[^/]+', 1, 2 ) AS sensor,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( topic, '[^/]+', 1, 4 ) AS measurement_name,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( topic, '[^/]+', 1, 5 ) AS measurement_metadata_type,
         value
  FROM   table_name
)
PIVOT(
  MAX( value )
  FOR ( measurement_name, measurement_metadata_type )
  IN  (
    ( 'MOISTURE', 'value'     ) AS MOISTURE_value,
    ( 'MOISTURE', 'unit'      ) AS MOISTURE_unit,
    ( 'MOISTURE', 'timestamp' ) AS MOISTURE_timestamp,
    ( 'CONDUCTIVITY', 'value'     ) AS CONDUCTIVITY_value,
    ( 'CONDUCTIVITY', 'unit'      ) AS CONDUCTIVITY_unit,
    ( 'CONDUCTIVITY', 'timestamp' ) AS CONDUCTIVITY_timestamp
  )
)
```

**Output**:

```
SENSOR_TYPE | SENSOR | MOISTURE_VALUE | MOISTURE_UNIT | MOISTURE_TIMESTAMP              | CONDUCTIVITY_VALUE | CONDUCTIVITY_UNIT | CONDUCTIVITY_TIMESTAMP         
:---------- | :----- | -------------: | :------------ | :------------------------------ | -----------------: | :---------------- | :------------------------------
SMARTBASE   | N0184  |           .414 | Raw VWC       | 01-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM |               .529 | mS/cm             | 01-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bfe91be0a3bc904e69c7fdd5a04be3bd)*